# How to cross out a quote in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a quote in beamer which I would to show crossed out, that is with a large cross going through it.  How can I do that?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{Example}
    \begin{exampleblock}{}
    {\large ``\blindtext''}
    \vskip5mm
    \hspace*\fill{\small--- Author and Author}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried `xcancel` from the `cancel` package but couldn't get it to work at all for this task.

Comment: Do you really work without a frame?

Comment: @TeXnician No. My example was just a little too minimal.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tikz` you could do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Example}

  \begin{exampleblock}{}
    {\large ``\blindtext''}
    \vskip5mm
    \hspace*\fill{\small--- Author and Author}
    \end{exampleblock}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[ultra thick,color=red] (0,0) -- (11,7) (11,0) -- (0,7);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My MWE didn't correctly show that the quote is at the bottom of the page.  Let me update it.

Comment: @Lembik Just modify the numbers in `(0,0) -- (11,7) (11,0) -- (0,7)`.

Comment: @Lembik That's exactly the method I used to derive the numbers in my answer :)